# How to change the string stored in the NSMutableDictionary itself which is pointed by many pointers?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutabledictionary

I have a string in the format str=`value|value|value|value|...` and it is stored in in an MutableDictionary I create as much as buttons as the number os string `value` in the string above by converting the string into array using

```
[str componentsSeparatedByString:@"|"]
```

and set that whole string to the title of the button.Below is the code I have explained above

```
[myMutableDictionary setObject:str forKey:date];
            NSArray *events=[str componentsSeparatedByString:@"|"];
            CGRect rect1=CGRectMake(0, 0,scheduleScroll.bounds.size.width, TIMEROWHWIGHT);
            for (NSString *strInfo in  events) {
                if([strInfo boolValue])
                {
                    NSArray *arr=[strInfo componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];

                    UIButton *btn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
                    rect1.size.height=TIMEROWHWIGHT*[[arr objectAtIndex:1] intValue];
                    [btn setTitle:[myMutableDictionary objectForKey:date] forState:UIControlStateApplication];
// add the Button as a sub view and define a method and target
```

the Buttons I've added will take the string I've added and change it and again set the changed string as the new vale for the same key (I keep a track on the keyValue currently worked on) in the selector I added for `touchupInside` `controlEvent`

My problem is that the changed string is not get reflected in the title property for `UIControlStateApplication` for all buttons I've added eventhough they have a pointer to the value of the key in that dictionary

Comment: Try setting the state to UIControlStateNormal instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing the UIButton creation code with this code :

```
 UIButton *btn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
 rect1.size.height=TIMEROWHWIGHT*[[arr objectAtIndex:1] intValue];
 [btn setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[myMutableDictionary objectForKey:date]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Use UIControlStateNormal instead of UIControlStateApplication unless you are specifically changing the state of the button to anything else but UIControlStateNormal (default).